# Protocol extension, does not conform to protocol, SwiftQueue library

Tags: ios, swift, extension-methods, swift-protocols

I am trying to use the SwiftQueue library. The problem is Xcode says:

> Type 'BackgroundJobCreator' does not conform to protocol 'JobCreator'

I have stripped back my class and made it as simplified as possible to find the problem.

```
class BackgroundJobCreator: JobCreator {

  func create(type: String, params: [String : Any]?)->Job {
      return BackgroundUploadService(params: params)
  }
}
```

Xcode asks "Do you want to add protocol subs", when I say yes it generates this..

```
func create(type: String, params: [String : Any]?) -> Job {
    [code]
}
```

The second I delete the old function, the error comes up again stating I am not conforming to protocol 'JobCreator'. The generated one is completely untouched. (I also can not have two as it raises "Invalid redeclaration of 'create(type:params:)'"

I even checked the library's source code to check the protocols were public

```
/// Protocol to create instance of your job
public protocol JobCreator {

/// method called when a job has be to instantiate
/// Type as specified in JobBuilder.init(type) and params as JobBuilder.with(params)
func create(type: String, params: [String: Any]?) -> Job

}
```

[SwiftQueue Protocols - Github](https://github.com/lucas34/SwiftQueue/blob/8bb3ae90abf05f4c15cad501a84df3751e680482/Sources/SwiftQueue/SwiftQueue.swift)

If the autogenerated protocols are wrong? Then it must be a mistake by the Swift compiler (or whatever checks this stuff)? I raised the issue on the GitHub a couple months back, but I feel this might be an isolated problem on my end.

EDIT: Here is the minimal code request to run..

```
import Foundation
import SwiftQueue

class BackgroundJobCreator: JobCreator {

func create(type: String, params: [String : Any]?)->Job {
      return BackgroundUploadService(params: params)
   }
}
```

-

```
import Foundation
import SwiftQueue

class BackgroundUploadService: Job{

  static let type = ""
  private var params: [String: Any]?

  required init(params: [String: Any]?) {
      // Receive params from JobBuilder.with()
      self.params = params
  }

  required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      fatalError("init(from:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

Comment: I created a simple test and don't get an error - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/baabe82e80f1392fea40c42bc7f1bfee

Comment: Yeah that is why I took this conversation from Github to stackoverflow.

Comment: You need to provide more code - we need a [mcve].  Try creating a new project, add the dependency and copy code from your current project until you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have added the minimal reproducible example as it only required 10 more lines. I will try starting a brand new project and trying this out.

Comment: Same Error in a new project

Comment: Well.. I copy pasted your code as is and it worked. Was having my code in two separate classes causing this silly error? Edit - Moving It over to my main project, and the bug is back.

Comment: I added your [mcve] code as two files in my project - Once I added the missing `onRun` `onRetry` and `onRemove` functions it compiled without issue.

Comment: Well I appreciate your help Paulw11, I found out another developer had added a Job object and it was conflicting with SwiftQueue's Job class. I wouldn't have narrowed that down if you didn't ensure me that it the code should work just fine.